# How to remove unwanted printer from ControlCenter4

Tags: usb, lan, brother-printer

When I installed ControlCenter4, I set it up to use my printer as both LAN and USB because my internet sometimes goes out. After some time, I have decided that I only want the USB option. The kicker is that when I accidentally close the program and reopen it later, it chooses the LAN version by default and I hit scan and have to wait for it to decide it isn't available. Is there a way to change the preferred printer or to remove the other method instead (only have the USB version in the dropdown)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using Windows Registry Editor (regedit), I was able to find past entries of printers on my system at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Brother\Brother MFL-Pro\MrMfInfo` (and also at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Brother\Brother MFL-Pro\MrMfInfo`). After removing an old entry there, my ControlCenter4 would no longer display it from the drop-down.

However, in my case, I actually changed the printer connection type so I ended up uninstalling ControlCenter and re-installed it from the full driver pack (available [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/productsearch.aspx?c=us&lang=en&content=dl)). This might be a simpler solution if editing windows registry goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Using Registery Editor navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Brother\ControlCenter\4.x\Model List and then delete the invalid scanner.

Comment: Worked for me thanks

Comment: You may need to restart your computer after doing this before it takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Windows 10. I had to find the uninstaller file for the Brother suite. You can use many different free utilities to get the registry value that is a command that uninstalls the software. This is how mine worked. My registry key for my add/remove (programs and features) menu command was:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{A1B36B88-AF90-43A3-8906-6DBEE89B4FBD}
```

the command was in the `uninstallstring` value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{A1B36B88-AF90-43A3-8906-6DBEE89B4FBD}\Setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 UNINSTALL Reg=BHmini11 -removeonly
```

I had to right click on the Setup.exe file and go to compatibility tab and set windows 8 compatibility mode, this will differ depending on your printer/OS combination. I had to run command prompt as administrator, then run the above command. This allowed the installer to remove it all, it had the brother printer name #2 #3 #4 #5 all checked for removal! After rebooting I was totally clean from all brother (I have a MFC-J435W). After this I installed my drivers that I downloaded from the support site. I strongly suggest setting win 8 compatibility mode on the setup file for that! Couldn't print certain things without the website driver.

THIS WORKS FOR OTHER SOFTWARE TOO

Answer (score -1):

Finally figured this out after a long time. It is so easy its stupid. Open up the brothers utilities app then hit tools. On tools it will have an uninstall button. Make sure if the top left corner drop down the correct printer/scanner you want to remove is selected. Then just hit uninstall.

Comment: He is asking how to remove from ControlCenter4 not Brother Utilities. ControlCenter4 will show scanners that do not appear in Brother Utilities.

Comment: Her answer will work in the vast majority of cases where the printer you want to get rid of is in both CC4 and Brother Utilities. Uninstalling her way will take it out of CC4