# Remove old devices from ControlCenter4

Tags: brother-printer

How do I remove all of the old devices/models listed from previous installations?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company). Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed. You can also contact the developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: Is this software on your computer? What have you tried so far? I'm guessing this list is stored in the registry of a config or ini file in the Brother installation. Have you checked either of these places? Where? What did you find?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove unwanted printer from ControlCenter4](https://superuser.com/questions/1259341/how-to-remove-unwanted-printer-from-controlcenter4)

Comment: Was there ever any resolution to this. Brother offers no help on this. Every computer in our organization has this problem with orphaned printers in their control center interface.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Windows 10. I had to find the uninstaller file for the Brother suite. You can use many different free utilities to get the registry value that is a command that uninstalls the software. This is how mine worked. My registry key for my add/remove (programs and features) menu command was:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{A1B36B88-AF90-43A3-8906-6DBEE89B4FBD}
```

the command was in the `uninstallstring` value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information{A1B36B88-AF90-43A3-8906-6DBEE89B4FBD}\Setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 UNINSTALL Reg=BHmini11 -removeonly
```

I had to right click on the Setup.exe file and go to compatibility tab and set windows 8 compatibility mode, this will differ depending on your printer/OS combination. I had to run command prompt as administrator, then run the above command. This allowed the installer to remove it all, it had the brother printer name #2 #3 #4 #5 all checked for removal! After rebooting I was totally clean from all brother (I have a MFC-J435W). After this I installed my drivers that I downloaded from the support site. I strongly suggest setting win 8 compatibility mode on the setup file for that! Couldn't print certain things without the website driver.

THIS WORKS FOR OTHER SOFTWARE TOO

Answer (score 0):

Without going into your registry:

If you have multiple "Model" profiles, try selecting from the `Control panel` >  `Uninstall a program` > `Brother Suite Etc.`
You will then be able to select the "Models" under the printer name as a tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that I ended up uninstallating the Brother utilities, deleting the printer and reinstalling the utilities again.
My situation was changing the printer connection from LAN to WLAN.  The Brother utility refused to recognise the printer change.
I did try the Registry changes but these were ignored.
It seems the utility can only work with EITHER a wired or wireless connected printer.  And doing what you might expect to setup the printer via Win10 didn't work.  Fairly hopeless.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).